# ember test to no run jshint

Tags: ember.js, jshint

I would like to run "ember test" without JShint.  My ultimate goal is to set run jshint in development environment and not run it in production build.

I first started to turn off the option in Brocfile.js
http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/disable-ember-cli-hinting/6731/2

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  hinting: false
});
```

It worked, so I decided to try

```
 var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app'),
  isProduction = ( process.env.EMBER_ENV || 'development' ) === 'production';


if( isProduction ){
   app.hinting = false;
}
```

Then I realize the process.env.EMBER_ENV, doesn't seem to work. But little did I know I was probably running the wrong command.

```
ember test
```

The command didn't specify any environment, so I tried

```
ember test --environment=production 
ember test --environment production
```

which result in an exception:

```
Build failed.
Path or pattern "test-loader.js" did not match any files
Error: Path or pattern "test-loader.js" did not match any files
  at Object.multiGlob (.../node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:202:13)
```

Next, I try to read node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js, I see:

```
  var isProduction = this.env === 'production';

  this.tests   = options.hasOwnProperty('tests')   ? options.tests   : !isProduction;
  this.hinting = options.hasOwnProperty('hinting') ? options.hinting : !isProduction;
```

But I don't really know how this.env get pass in the ember test and I can't get the environment within the Brocfil.js.  I am assuming by default, hinting would respect the isProduction value if it isn't defined.

And searching further more, got me to https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-cli-test-loader, which seems to be related.

My questions are:
1. Is there a way to run ember test without jshint via CLI?
2. Can this be set using config/environment.js?
3. Can I set a breakpoint to debug the Brocfile.js file?  I tried with chrome:localhost:4200, I don't any node_modules file being loaded.

Thanks in advance. I am an extreme newbie to javascript and ember..

Comment: Why are you running your tests in production?

Comment: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9345  - related to ember test --environment=production

Comment: I am running tests in production, just want to turn off jshint tests

Comment: I thought ember build --environment=production would build something for production, and ember test --environment=production would run unit/integration test, without jshint.  (at least that's what I want when running maven build for production)  Please advice.

Answer (score 1):

try

`ember test --query=nolint`

the latest ember-cli-qunit uses this query param to disable lint checks in tests

[here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-qunit/blob/6a4d5c549fdb2d9b18c122e94b82de3060299d71/vendor/ember-cli-qunit/qunit-configuration.js#L4) is the commit where it was added if you are interested